# Google Script for Dynamic Dropdown in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to scripts and programming . I have used the below code and triggered(time trigger every minute,since trigger on form submit did not work well) the job, this worked earlier and data updated in form drop down. But currently the newest data is not being updated and when I run manually it shows "Array is empty". What can i do to avoid this problem permanently?

```
enter code here
var ssId = '...';
var formId = '...';
var sheetName = 'Item_Group_FormCopy';
var column = 'N';
var listItemId = 1617939596;
var ssdata= SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
var form= FormApp.openById(formId);`
function dropdowniteminward(values){
  var label=ssdata.getRange(2,14,ssdata.getMaxRows()-1).getValues();
  var values=[];
  for(var i=0;i<label.length;i++)
    if(label[i][0]!="")
      values[i]=label[i][0];
 var form=FormApp.openById(formId);
 var item=form.getItemById(listItemId);
 item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Hi there @HarikaAvirneni! Could you please explain why the `OnFormSubmit` trigger didn't work well? Maybe we all can help you to make it work. After studying your code I don't see any reason why it shouldn't populate the array. To prevent missing any important details, could you repeat the operation including every variable inside the scope of the function? Finally, if that didn't work, could you share a sample spreadsheet with us? Please, remember to delete any private identifiable information.

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron, Thank you for the response. The problem is resolved once I changed the run time of each script. So that they all do not run at the same time. Since All the forms has input data from same spreadsheet, though that might be an issue and has done so. This is working fine.